# Caused by: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] no native library is found for os.name=Linux and os.arch=x86_64

Tags: java, apache-kafka, snappy

*What I would like to achieve:*

Run a kafka consumer with native / aot / graalvm

*Issue:*

When running the application, I am facing this 100% reproducible issue:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Received exception when fetching the next record from my-topic-1. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1676)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.access$1900(Fetcher.java:1497)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:717)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.collectFetch(Fetcher.java:683)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1314)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1243)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
    at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.ConsumerEventLoop$PollEvent.run(ConsumerEventLoop.java:357)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] no native library is found for os.name=Linux and os.arch=x86_64
    at org.apache.kafka.common.compress.SnappyFactory.wrapForInput(SnappyFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.CompressionType$3.wrapForInput(CompressionType.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch.recordInputStream(DefaultRecordBatch.java:276)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch.compressedIterator(DefaultRecordBatch.java:280)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch.streamingIterator(DefaultRecordBatch.java:364)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.nextFetchedRecord(Fetcher.java:1619)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1656)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] no native library is found for os.name=Linux and os.arch=x86_64
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.findNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:343)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:177)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadSnappyApi(SnappyLoader.java:155)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.init(Snappy.java:70)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:47)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.readFully(SnappyInputStream.java:145)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.readHeader(SnappyInputStream.java:99)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.<init>(SnappyInputStream.java:59)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.compress.SnappyFactory.wrapForInput(SnappyFactory.java:44)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

*What I tried:*

In my dependencies, I do have the most recent Snappy:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
            <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

On my machine, Ubuntu, I do have Snappy installed.

```
root@dlp:~# apt -y install snapd
root@dlp:~# systemctl  enable snapd.service snapd.socket
root@dlp:~# source /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh
```

*Question:*

How to fix this exception?

Comment: `apt-get install snappy-java` see [also](https://github.com/xerial/snappy-java)

Comment: snapd is a daemon for a package manager, not a serialization library, or have anything to do Snappy... Your Maven dependency is not "native libraries", only Java classes, which require C modules to be installed on the OS

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thank you for the comment. I tried ```apt-get install snappy-java``` and it is giving me "package not found"

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you for the comment, which C modules please? I tried ```sudo apt-get install gcc zlib1g-dev build-essential``` still no luck

Comment: `libsnappy-dev`, I believe https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libsnappy-dev

Comment: hey @OneCricketeer, the ```libsnappy-dev``` seems to work. Would you like to put it as an answer? I will upvote+accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do have Snappy installed.

[Snap / snapd](https://ubuntu.com/core/services/guide/snaps-intro) is not the same as [Snappy](https://google.github.io/snappy/) .

You should install the latter with [`libsnappy-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libsnappy-dev), as that is the native libraries that the error is referring to. The Java dependency requires those.

If you don't need Snap applications, then you can *uninstall* snapd